# Django's sitemap framework giving error when using aggregate max function on lastmod

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-2.0

I'm trying to use Django's sitemap framework feature. I've implemented the code and it works with current article objects post_date. However I'm trying to get a more accurate last modification date using the following code and it gives me error. Traceback of error http://dpaste.com/3Z04VH8

Regards.
Thanks for any help

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.db.models import Max
from article.models import Article


class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'hourly'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Article.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        from post.models import Post
        return Post.objects.filter(article=obj).aggregate(Max('post_date'))
        #return obj.post_date
```

Comment: You need to show the `Post` model and include the traceback here in the question.

Comment: The linked traceback doesn't seem to be related to the problem being described here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lastmod` method in the `Sitemap` class needs to return a `datetime` object. Instead you are returning a dictionary (which is what `aggregate` will produce) - which is invalid.

You need to fetch the data from inside that dictionary and return that:

```
result = Post.objects.filter(article=obj).aggregate(Max('post_date'))
# result will look something like {'post_date__max': Datetime('2017-12-06')}
return result['post_date__max']
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking it is returning Datetime instance.